# session_unset VS session_reset

Tags: php, session, difference

I want to know what is the difference between `session_unset` and `session_reset`.

Both of them clears `$_SESSION` data, so what is their difference, and can you give me an example for each one?

Comment: Check their respective docs pages.  [`session_reset`](http://php.net/session_reset) — Re-initialize session array with original values.  [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset) — Free all session variables

Comment: `session_reset()` does not clear session data it rolls the the session back to its original values.  see the first note in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-reset.php

Comment: @cmorrissey That example doesn't work for me , it gives me an error .

Comment: @RocketHazmat : I made two file , one of them for session_reset , another one for session_unset , in both of the files I defined $_SESSION variables , after that I used session_reset() in one file , session_unset in another file , then I used var_dump($_SESSION) , both of the files output was array(0){} ...

Comment: @Parsamhn: That's just a coincidence.  `session_reset` says it "Re-initializes session array with original values".  What were the *original* values in `$_SESSION` before you called `session_reset`?  If you started with an empty session, added data to it, then called `session_reset`, it's gonna revert to an empty session.  Try to add some session data, change that data, then call `session_reset`.

Comment: @Parsamhn: Actually.  It seems that `session_reset` will revert back to whatever was in `$_SESSION` *before* your script was called.  Try to start a session, add some data to it, then load *another page* with `session_reset` and see what happens.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know session_reset should rolling back changes but as ahmad suggests , I used the code below , but it gives an error : Notice: Undefined index: A

Comment: @Parsamhn: Yeah, I think that `session_reset` will revert back to whatever was in `$_SESSION` before your script was called.  Looks like that example should be two different files.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I will do this , so I think I should change my question with Problem with session_reset() , lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are wrong. `session_reset` is for rolling back changes that has made to the session.

See this example, from PHP documentation (a little different):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["A"] = "Some Value";
?>
```

Execute this code first and then, execute this:

```
<?php
    start_session();
    $_SESSION["A"] = "Some New Value";  // set new value

    session_reset();  // old session value restored
    echo $_SESSION["A"];

    //Output: Some Value
?>
```

That is because `session_reset()` is rolling back changes to the last saved session data, which is their values right after the `session_start()`.

Comment: thank you , I saw that example in php.net , but this code doesn't work for me , when I use session_reset(); then I echo $_SESSION['A'] , it give me an error : Notice: Undefined index: A

Comment: @Parsamhn: There are 2 `echo $_SESSION['A']`s here.  Which one gave you that message?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This example is not a good one. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Ahmad: I think `session_reset` may reset the session to what it was *before* the script was ran.  It looks like this example should be two separate files, maybe?

Comment: @RocketHazmat the last one .

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes, I was writing same thing!